# How to navigate to a composable via notification in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to navigate user to a screen after clicked on the notification I have sent. There some limited articles about this subject. I tried them but I could not achieve to do the action. My code :

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "main") {
                composable("main") {
                    main(this@MainActivity)
                }
                composable("testScreen") {
                    testScreen()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun main(mainActivity: MainActivity) {
    val postNotificationPermission = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
    val waterNotificationService = WaterNotificationService(mainActivity)


    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (!postNotificationPermission.status.isGranted) {
            postNotificationPermission.launchPermissionRequest()
        }
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            waterNotificationService.showBasicNotification()
        }) {
            Text("SHOW NOTIFICATION")

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun testScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("TEST SCREEN WELCOME")
    }
}
```

manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:name=".WaterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NotificationNavigation"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver android:name="com.yunusulucay.healthylife.AlarmSetup.AlarmReceiverBreath"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NotificationNavigation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here I only want to do is after I click button it will show some notification and after I click on that notification I want it to navigate me to testScreen() composable. If you can give me a simple example about this it will be better.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use deepLinking features of compose navigation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set actionIntent and pendingIntent for notification and then you will have to get intent extras in `onCreate` or `onNewIntent` depending on the activity's lifecycle.

Something like this:

```
val activityActionIntent = Intent(context, YourActivity::class.java).apply {
            this.putExtra("testingIntent", true)
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        }
        val pendingIntentFlag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        val activityActionPendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            requestCode,
            activityActionIntent,
            pendingIntentFlag
        )
        val nBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notificationChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
                .setContentIntent(activityActionPendingIntent)

        notificationManager.notify(REMINDER_ID, nBuilder.build())
```

In onCreate:

```
    setContent {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>()
            val navigateToTestView = intent.getBooleanExtra("testIntent", false)
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            val startDestination = if(navigateToTestView) "testScreen" else "main"

            NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
                composable("main") {
                    main(this@MainActivity, navigateToTestView)
                }
                composable("testScreen") {
                    testScreen()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to navigate to test screen from mainView then just send that boolean in mainView and use navController to navigate from LaunchedEffect